# Spark Query on S3 Json Files

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql

We need to download certain JSON files from S3 and then query over the JSON files via spark

`sqc.read.option("header", params.header).json(filePaths: _*)`

Now the one of the many ways is to use hadoop-aws s3 dependency and then use either `S3AFileSystem` but we do not want to use this methodology due to certain performance implications in the hadoop-aws library as there could be too many API calls for parquet files.

So we are looking for simpler methodology in which in a single job we can do the following

- download a Json File from S3
- run a SQL Query over this Json Files via `sqc.read.option("header", params.header).json(filePaths: _*)`

We tried using our own `FileFormat` and then `HadoopFSRelation` but there are still a lot of unsolved issues.

So has anybody tried to query a file on S3 via spark without hadoop-aws ?

Comment: Downloading files and then querying them isn't a very common design pattern, it'll be very slow and you'll incur a lot of network traffic. Generally you'd either use AWS EMR or install Spark yourself in EC2 instances. Both of these methods can access files on S3 directly and quickly.

Comment: Using Spark to Query S3 directly will also result into more or less the same amount of network traffic and API requests. @BenWatson

Comment: There's a difference between downloading files to what I presume is a local file system and running Spark directly against S3. You want to move the computation to the data and not the other way round.

Comment: Ofcourse I will want to move the computation to the data but how can i run spark JOB against S3 and not download data from S3.